# Java - Reading text file and storing it in an objects inside a class

Tags: java

I have a super class and 2 subclasses.

My super class is "Employee" with a name and monthlySalary.

My 1st subclass is "Salesman" with an additional instance variable called annualSales.

My2nd subclass is "Executive" with an additional instance variable called called stockPrice.

I have a text file that includes 
"year, firstname,lastname, monthlySalary" 
"year, firstname,lastname, monthlySalary, annualSales"
"year, firstname,lastname, monthlySalary, stockPrice"

**Big question: How do I store the information from my text file into my superclass and two subclasses?**

I have this in my main method. After some tips here I tried updating it. Again thank you for the help, I am trying to understand this to succeed. I am very new to programming in general.

```
public class Project1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


FileReader fr =new FileReader("C:\\Users\\JakobJundi\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Project1\\src\\project1\\information.txt");
BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fr);
String fileLine;
fileLine = br.readLine();
String[] fields = fileLine.split(" ");

Employee employee1 = new Employee(fields[0],Double.parseDouble(fields[1]));

//Salesman salesman1 = new Salesman (fields[0], Double.parseDouble(fields[1]), Double.parseDouble(fields[2]));

//Executive executive1 = new Executive (fields[0], Double.parseDouble(fields[1]), Double.parseDouble(fields[2]));

System.out.println(employee1);
//System.out.println(salesman1);
//System.out.println(executive1);



  fields = fileLine.split(" ");
  if (fields.length == 2){

  Salesman salesman1 = new Salesman(fields[0], Double.parseDouble(fields[1]), Double.parseDouble(fields[2]));
  System.out.println(salesman1);
  }

 }
 }
```

This is my Employee super class:

```
public class Employee {

 final String name;
 final double monthlySalary;
 private double annualSalary;

 public Employee(String name, double monthlySalary) {
  System.out.println("Constructing an Employee");
  this.name = name;
  this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
 }



  @Override
  public String toString() {
  return "Name: " + name + "--" + "Monthly salary: " + monthlySalary;
  }

 //getters
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

  public double getMonthlySalary() {
  return monthlySalary;
 }

  public double getAnnualSalary(){
    return monthlySalary * 12;
  }

 //setters
 public void setannualSalary(double newannualSalary) {
  annualSalary = newannualSalary;
 }
 }
```

And this is one out of my 2 subclasses.

```
public class Salesman extends Employee {

private final double annualSales; // Annual sales
private double annualSalary;


 public Salesman(String name, double monthlySalary, double annualSales) {
  super(name, monthlySalary);
  this.annualSales = annualSales;
  System.out.println("Constructing a Salesman");
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Name: " + name + "--" + "Monthly salary: " + monthlySalary;
 }

 public double getAnnualSales() {
  return annualSales;
 }

  @Override
 public double getAnnualSalary(){
   return (monthlySalary * 12) + (annualSales * 0.02);
 }

  @Override
 public void setannualSalary(double newannualSalary) {
  annualSalary = newannualSalary;
  } 
 }
```

When running this I get this output: 
**Constructing an Employee
Name: Jundi,jakob--Monthly salary: 2000.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at project1.Project1.main(Project1.java:49)**

Comment: You declare Employee employee1 = new Employee(); but you never pass any values into the constructor. You need to pass in values for String name and double monthlySalary in order to correctly create a new Employee. You also are not parsing the file for any information to be passed into the Employee class.

Comment: I don't understand your problem now. So far you're just reading the file line wise but not doing anything with each line besides printing it to console. What about processing each line, i.e. extracting the attributes and assigning those to an employee (for each line)?

Comment: I think that is where I am having the hangup. I simply can't figure out how to do that and extract the attributes from my text file into my employee class. I've been reading all day, but can't figure out how to assign the information from my text file, into the employee class, the salesman subclass and the executive subclass.

Comment: Use `String[] fields = fileLine.split(",")` to break out the comma-delimited fields from each input line into the `String` array `fields`.  For those fields corresponding to `int` or `double` attributes of your classes, you can then use `Integer.parseInt` or `Double.parseDouble` to convert them.

Comment: I tried using that and now my output is:                                                                      Constructing an Employee
Name: Jundi,jakob--Monthly salary: 2000.0
Constructing an Employee
Name: Jones,Bill--Monthly salary: 3000.0
Constructing an Employee
Name: Bush,George--Monthly salary: 5000.0

Comment: So it seems I can store the information from my information.txt into my superclass and show it in the console without an issue. However I can't seem to initialize my subclasses. I tried this: Salesman salesman1 = new Salesman (fields[0], Double.parseDouble(fields[1]), Double.parseDouble(fields[2]));                                                                              however it gives me an indexoutofboundsexception. What I am trying to do is, store the textfile's first line consisting of two items (name,name monthlySalary) into my my superclass and have it take effect in my subclasses.

Comment: So basically you are storing the data in the text file? And you want to get that text file once your code is running and then set the value from that text file to those instance variables of the super and subclasses?

Comment: Correct, I have a name and a monthly salary in the text file, which I want to store into the super (Empmloyee). The subclass (salesman) has an extra value called stockPrice. My text documents first line has (name,name monthlySalary), the second line of my text file has (name,name monthlySalary stockPrice). The superclass is supposed to print out the name, the monthlySalary and a yearly salary. The subclass is supposed to print out the name from line 2 in my text file, calculate a new monthly salary based on stockPrice formula. Then there is a third class. Can't figure out how to store it inall

Comment: I can update the question above with what I have so far in terms of main method, superclass and subclasses?